# In the figure below, the side length of of the smaller square is 4, and the area of the red region is 1. What is the area of the larger square?

Tags: geometry

I already did some progress and labeled some similar segments.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red triangle has area $1$ but it has base and height $x$ so the area will be $x^2/2=1$ so $x^2=2$ and finally $x=\sqrt 2$. By the Pythagorean theorem we also have that $y^2=x^2+4^2=4^2+\sqrt 2^2=18$. But $y^2$ is just the area of the larger square since it's the side lenght squared. So the area will be $18$